# How to PHP shell_exec a command output script allert success/failed and redirect to index page

Tags: php, bash

I'm totally new to PHP.
There is running a PHP script shell_exec calling a command scp.sh
It's working good. Now I just wanted a prompt / alert showing the success/fail message. And then redirect to index.php.

Here is my php 
transfer.php

```
    $old_path = getcwd();        
    chdir('/root/');        
    $output = shell_exec('sudo sh scp.sh');        
    chdir($old_path);
```

Bash file scp.sh  content

```
#!/bin/bash                  
scp -r /usr/mail/* user@host:/root/mail/
```

Please help me.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
if scp -r /usr/mail/* user@host:/root/mail/ ; then
    echo "Command succeeded"
else
    echo "Command failed"
fi
```

That is how you would see a success/fail message in bash depending on the command succeeding or failing. If you want a php message then go to php section.